# How to spawn multiple clones of picturebox1 in random locations on button click?

Tags: c#, winforms

We are making a zombie game for school with Visual Studio 10.

We want to randomly spawn Zombies, a.k.a. PictureBoxes.
All these pictureboxes need their own coordinates, because if the players coordinates are the same as the zombie, the player needs to lose HP.

I am looking for this function for 3 days now, so I thought why not ask a professional advice here?

We now only have this code to let one (Picturebox) zombie walk:

```
private void ZombieLopenOne()
        {
            // Begin Zombie Lopen
            int zombx = EenZombie1.Location.X;
            int zomby = EenZombie1.Location.Y;
            if ( zomby > 420 + EenZombie1.Height ) {
                zomby = -EenZombie1.Height;
                EenZombie1.Location = new Point(zombx, zomby);
            }
            else
            {
                zomby += 3;
                EenZombie1.Location = new Point(zombx, zomby);
            }
            // End Zombie Lopen

          }
```

Can you help us out?

Comment: I'm afraid you will have to post some more code... What is EenZombie1? Is it a pictureBox? What have you done to have more than 1 Zombie? Do you want his original position to be random? Did you wrap a PictureBox inside a derived class?

Comment: I just simply want to get images of Zombies spawn'ed all over the place!

Comment: Can you post the code part that create and store them? My guess is you should have a list somewhere? You said the method above is to make them walk, right?

Comment: Well, the part that creates and stores them is the one I'm currently looking for my friend :)! Can I put images in a listbox? And Yes! The method above is to make them walk!

Comment: So, what have you tried to spawn them?

Comment: Unfortunately I don't know how

Comment: It's a bit tricky then, because this website is not to code it for you, but help you in when you have a specific code problem. In this case, I would invite you to read about `List<>`, arrays or any type of table containers. You will also have to add each new `PictureBox` to the `Controls` list property of your form so they are displayed.

Comment: Ok, thank you for your kind advice LightStriker!

Answer (score 0):

You can use a `List<T>`, which will contain all the zombies. A zombie is a simple class called Zombie. The class contains the x and the y coordinate of the zombie. In the Paint-Event of the Form, the program loops throught all elements in your List and draws a texture on the window.

In your code of your window:

```
class Zombie {
   public Zombie(int x, int y) {
      this.x = x;
      this.y = y;
   }
   public int x;
   public int y;
}

List<Zombie> zombies;

//Constructor of your window
public MainWindow() {
   InitializeComponet(); //This is autogenerated by Visual Studio
   this.Paint += new PaintEventHandler(Paint);
   zombies = new List<Zombie>;
}

public void Paint(object sender, PaintEventArgs e) {
   foreach(Zombie zombie in zombies) {
      e.Graphics.DrawImage(/*Your zombie image*/, new Point(zombie.x, zombie.y));
   }
}
```

You can add and remove zombies using the methods of the `List<T>` class.